# Who are allowed to put Akshathi on couple performing puja?

Tags: rituals, marriage, puja

In a Tamil thread ceremony function, who all can put akshathai. Can this be put only by senior members who are elder to the one performing the pujai (Dampathis)? Can this be put by a non Hindu person (Christian) ?

Who are allowed to put akshati and bless the couple?